# how to use local storage in wkhtmltopdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, wkhtmltopdf

To display an item (whose key is "myinfo"), previously stored locally in the browser, I use something like:

```
$('div:first').html( localStorage.getItem('myinfo') );
```

It works well until I open a PDF generated on this page using `wkhtmltopdf`. In that case, my DIV's content is empty, showing that the localStorage function returned `null`.

Now that would suggest to me that the `webkit` engine underneath `wkhtmltopdf` does not implement localStorage.

Is that the correct reason for this behaviour?

How else can I store and retrieve stuff locally using `javascript` and `wkhtmltopdf`?

Comment: LocalStorage is per (sub)domain, did your domain changed after running wkhtmltopdf?

Comment: @NaturalLam: No, the domain is the same. But as you might see from my answer below, it dawns on me the browser engine doing the saving and the one trying to retrieve are actually different.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I've thought through, and can answer the first part of my question:

> Is that the correct reason for this behaviour?

No, it isn't.

The reason my approach won't work is:

I saved some data to local storage on "page1.html" in Browser1. Now going to "page2.html" on the same browser, I called wkhtmltopdf (via an AJAX request to the server). Since wkhtmltopdf is essentially another browser (let's call it "Browser2"), there's no way it's going to be able to access data that was previously saved by "Browser1".

Therefore, it's looking increasing to me like: there's no way to programmatically persist data between my Browser1 and wkhtmltopdf without first saving that data on the server. If I am wrong, then my second question:

> How else can I store and retrieve stuff locally using javascript and
>   wkhtmltopdf?

is still waiting for an answer!